# Filter list with condition and return results as delimited list in a single cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007

I need to return all values in column A that match a set criterion in Column B.

The returned values need to be in a single cell in a single formula.

[image: Sample]

In the attached Sample image, I need a single formula (I'm guessing it will be an array formula) that will return all the results where the `Group Name` is "Service Desk".

So I would expect the results to be:

```
Cesare Rutger<BR>
Diarmait Oliver<BR>
Vladislav Corraidhín
```

Comment: Unfortunately having all values returned to a SINGLE cell is unfeasible using worksheet formulas alone, and would require VBA. Having them returned to separate cells is doable using formulas, however, if that is something you would consider.

Comment: Well i'm looking to use the formula as a source in a data validation list. Basically, I have a long list of Agent Names, but I want to use a subset of that list in a data validation list. Is this possible without too much work in regards to creating additional lists and sheets etc...?

Comment: But a Data Validation list which references cells in the worksheet will not work as desired if you reference a single cell containing a delimited list. Or do you have evidence to the contrary?

Comment: what type of data validation list? normal data validation list in Excel has a range as a source, not a single cell. Have a look on these links, they may answer your root question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16218332/excel-data-validation-list-using-formula-with-filtering, http://chandoo.org/wp/2008/11/25/advanced-data-validation-techniques-in-excel-spreadcheats/

Comment: Can I not specify a formula as the source? Or in this case an array formula?

Comment: Like I said, you can, but the list which that formula generates must refer to an actual worksheet range, which is why I proposed having each return in separate (contiguous) cells. And I'm still not sure why you are opposing this idea.

Comment: I'm not opposed. :) Whatever solution works. :)

Answer (score 0):

Use an additional range in the workbook somewhere to store the reduced list. D3:D10 within your current table would seem to suggest itself, so enter this formula (which assumes you have Excel 2010 or later) in D3:

`=IF(ROWS($1:1)>COUNTIF(C$3:C$10,"Service Desk"),"",INDEX(B:B,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(C$3:C$10)/(C$3:C$10="Service Desk"),ROWS($1:1))))`

and copy down to D10.

Then go to Name Manager (Formulas tab) and define:

*Name*: `List`
*Refers to*: `=$D$3:INDEX($D$3:$D$10,MATCH(TRUE,$D$3:$D$10="",0)-1)`

Your required Data Validation is then to choose the *List* option with this formula in the *Source* box:

`=List`

Regards